# Shorten formular (example: s = ((-a / x) + b) / ((c / x) + d))

Tags: vectors, fractions

Hello im currently studding math in High school / college level,

And today we had to calculate if 2 3d-vectors would cross each other, and since i diddent like to go though the 5-6 steps the book taugth us, i came up with a formular that could handle most of the steps in 1 take.

---

The goal is to calculate **S** (and **T**) so you can calculate the point of collision if any exist.

I get two 3d-vectors as following: "i.stack.imgur.com/XmFEn.png"

Where **L** = Lenght of the vector, and **O** = Oriantation of the vector.

These numbers can all be positive, negative and zero.

2. on the picture shows the real math questions data.

I guess no more detail is required since the question is about how to shorten (if you can) a formular of this type and not how to get to this formular.

---

The most basic way to show the formular would be this:

[image]

*Are there anyway to remove both of the **X**'es, Or in anyway shorten the formular?*

---

The real formula is this one:

[image]

where the last is the current state of the formula.

Comment: If you don't write *the whole original* question and **show** what you did, it is going to be tough to guess what is going on here (beyond guessing that you have two lines/vectors in parametric form nad etc.), even if you add a picture.

Comment: Do you need more information than whay i provided in the updated question? :)

Comment: You can in the last three case multiply numerator and denominator by x1t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there anyway to remove both of the $x$'s, Or in anyway shorten the formula?

No, not really. You can multiply by $x/x=1$, to get an expression without fractions within fractions:

$$\frac{b-\frac{a}{x}}{d+\frac{c}{x}}=\frac{bx-a}{dx+c},$$

but no further simplification can be achieved (without any further information about the parameters at least).

Comment: Okay i can try to update the question with more information about the parameters :) But fast: They can all be positive and negative numbers (no intervals)

Comment: @user1509104 Their sign doesn't matter, as long as $dx\not=c$ and $x\not=0$.

Comment: I just updated my question, are there any more information i should offer? :)